# Checking condition in call method of custom layer using tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gradienttape

I'm implementing a custom layer in tensorflow 2.x . My requirement is such that, the program should check a condition before returning the output.

```
class SimpleRNN_cell(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, M1, M2, fi=tf.nn.tanh, disp_name=True):
        super(SimpleRNN_cell, self).__init__()
        pass        
    def call(self, X, hidden_state, return_state=True):
        y = tf.constant(5)
        if return_state == True:
            return y, self.h
        else:
            return y
```

My question is: should I continue using the present code (assuming that the `tape.gradient(Loss, self.trainable_weights)` will work fine) or should I use `tf.cond()`.
Also, if possible please explain where to use `tf.cond()` and where not to. I haven't found much content on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.cond` is only relevant when performing conditional evaluation based on data in the differentiable computation graph. (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) This was especially necessary in TF 1.0 with graph mode being the default. For eager mode the `GradientTape` system allows to also do conditional data flow with the python constructs such as `if ...:` (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#control_flow)

Yet for just providing different behavior based on configuration parameters, that don't depend on data from the computational graph and are fixed during the model runtime, using simple python `if` statements is correct.

Comment: Got it :)  But what if ```y``` was not fixed in the code and was dependent on some calculation? so I don't need ```tf.cond``` unless I'm using ```@tf.function```. Is that what you mean?

Comment: In principle most of that is also covered by the autograph features. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs#flow_control_and_side_effects https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#conditionals But some restrictions apply: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/control_flow.md#if-statements And side-effects could cause issues https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/control_flow.md#effects-of-the-tracing-process